# Is it possible to solve Rubik's cube using DQN?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, dqn

I'm trying to solve Rubik's cube using deep learning and I came across with DQN, so I decided to give it a try. I developed all the code and started training but I got this results:
[image]

Loss goes up and test never get better results. I have tried to change learning rate, epsilon greedy decay, reducing scramble moves to one but it still can't solve it with just one move. That's why I would like to know if it just impossible to do it this way or I could miscalculating some values.

Comment: Is the question theoretical - "is it possible?" or practical - "how to do it"?

Answer (score 0):

I think yes, you can, since rubric group can be represented as a grid word environment.

See this [link](https://github.com/sekharcvs/RubiksCube) from GitHub, they attempted solving using dqn